# SFBot stopped working on several servers

Tags: networking

SFBot stopped working on several servers. I'm using latest version `2.1.0` downloaded from `sfbot.de`.

Confirmed affected servers: `Poland` -> `Świat 3`

Comment: You probably need to add more information to make this question answerable. When did they stop working, and what changed? What errors are you seeing? Also, this probably belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: this shoud be mo0ved to stackoverflow MMO site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reverse engineering of packets send between server I found solution. This program downloads server list and parsing this list and then set up addresses of servers. The problem is in parsing procedure.

I found method described here: http://help.sfbot.de/tips/tips.html#server to manualy add custom server.

In file: `server.sfb` you must add following lines to force server address:

```
<country name="POLAND" url="http://www.sfgame.pl">
    <server name="POLAND3" url="http://s3.sfgame.pl" />
</country>
```

After that simply user must edit account's data and choose new country and server entered above.